# Manipulating Pyspark dataframes for the LSTM model

Tags: python, pandas, keras, pyspark, lstm

I am trying to train a LSTM neural network for text prediction.
I have a dataframe with 3.5 million chess games written as strings. 
For examples:

[image]

I have parsed, tokenized and made the game the same length. To do this I have used an udf function so that I have a list of integers identifying the moves made during the game.

Once this is done my model accepts as input A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].
(I use the keras LSTM: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/)

To do this I thought of converting my pyspark dataframe to pandas and use numpy but I can't do that because i'm developing it on databricks communty edition it always gives me out of memory problems.

Can someone tell me how i can solve this problem? Since I can't convert it to pandas because of the OOM problem can anyone suggest me another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store the games as strings - store them as integers or, better, binary encoded values.  This method would reduce your memory storage considerably and it would have the added benefit of being more amenable to computation.  Using a relational schema, you would have `games`->`moves`, where `games` would store demographics (names, wins) and `moves` would just be a list of numerically-encoded exchanges.

You can still process the values as strings/words/whatever, because the computer doesn't need human text to produce a model.  Of course, if it's a generative model, you'll have to perform reverse translation on the backside, but this would be trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Since I asked this question I have moved on and now I have opened another one! If you can help me with the other one I would be grateful. This is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893428/input-for-lstm-model