# Input for LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, shapes

I am trying to train an LSTM model for string prediction, specifically chess moves.

I have a very large dataset and it contains chess games in string form.
The form of the game in the dataset is:

```
"W1.d4 B1.d5 W2.c4 B2.e6 W3.Nc3 B3.Nf6 W4.cxd5 B4.exd5 W5.Bg5 B5.Be7 W6.e3 B6.Ne4 W7.Bxe7 B7.Nxc3 W8.Bxd8 B8.Nxd1 W9.Bxc7 B9.Nxb2 W10. Rb1 B10.Nc4 W11.Bxc4 B11.dxc4 W12.Ne2 B12.O-O W13.Nc3 B13.b6 W14.d5 B14.Na6 W15.Bd6 B15.Rd8 W16.Ba3 B16.Bb7 W17.e4 B17.f6 W18. Ke2 B18.Nc7 W19.Rhd1 B19.Ba6 W20.Ke3 B20.Kf7 W21.g4 B21.g5 W22.h4 B22.h6 W23.Rh1 B23.Re8 W24.f3 B24.Bb7 W25.hxg5 B25.fxg5 W26.d6 B26. Nd5+ W27.Nxd5 B27.Bxd5 W28.Rxh6 B28.c3 W29.d7 B29.Re6 W30.Rh7+ B30.Kg8 W31.Rbh1 B31.Bc6 W32.Rh8+ B32.Kf7 W33.Rxa8 B33.Bxd7 W34.Rh7+"
```

I parsed and converted every single move of the games into integers.
In my parse I only kept the move, so I deleted the part before the dot. 
For example:

```
W1.d4 -> d4
```

So every integer corresponds to one move and in my dataset I have 10045 moves.
and the game then becomes:

```
[10045, 10045, 10045, 10045, 10045, 10045, 10045, 10045, 3379, 9178, 2967, 905, 6732, 9052, 5734, 7150, 6300, 5585, 2801, 824, 8392, 8968, 7976, 2156, 6775, 4410, 8345, 8029, 147, 5845, 4001, 5841, 6732, 4705, 9178, 1665, 9409, 6930, 4521, 8954, 6215, 7726, 7911, 5083, 4407, 5130, 6021, 7516, 5226, 5166, 8667, 9410, 6636, 2068, 2892, 8954, 1455, 10033, 7335, 3543, 3103, 9571, 3619, 4810, 774, 1877, 7597, 701, 2050, 509, 8585, 7516, 803, 2158, 7597]
```

Notice that the move 10045 is used to fill matches and bring them all to the same length. Furthermore, I don't have the state of the board, so I was only going to predict moves using string sequences.

So each integer corresponds to one move and in my dataset I have 10045 moves.

```
{'Qcxe6+': '0', 'Rhg5': '1', 'R1xc4+': '2', 'Qcxf3+': '3', ... }
```

Once that was done I moved on to creating X_train and Y_train for my model.
I split the matches the 5 timesteps and decided to start by taking only 5 matches for the moment.
In the creation of my X_train I then made a join of these 5 matches divided by timesteps as if it were one big batch. Then I normalised my X_train by dividing it by the number of available moves (10045).
An example in my X_train:

```
[[[0.33638626182180187]
  [0.9011448481831758]
  [0.295370831259333]
  [0.09009457441513191]
  [0.6434046789447486]]

 [[0.9011448481831758]
  [0.295370831259333]
  [0.09009457441513191]
  [0.6434046789447486]
  [0.9136884021901444]]

 [[0.295370831259333]
  [0.09009457441513191]
  [0.6434046789447486]
  [0.9136884021901444]
  [0.6701841712294674]]

 ...

 [[0.3886510701841712]
  [0.8913887506222001]
  [0.40159283225485315]
  [0.6532603285216526]
  [0.21682429069188652]]

 [[0.8913887506222001]
  [0.40159283225485315]
  [0.6532603285216526]
  [0.21682429069188652]
  [0.44649079143852666]]

 [[0.40159283225485315]
  [0.6532603285216526]
  [0.21682429069188652]
  [0.44649079143852666]
  [0.9367844698855152]]]
```

Once I've done this I've moved on to creating my Y_tain which will contain the labels for each timesteps of the matches in X_train.
I have chosen to encode these labels with a baseN encoding, more precisely in base 5 and since I have 10045 different moves, in Y the moves are encoded with 6 bits and therefore with a list of 6 integers. 
An example of my Y_tain:

```
[[2 4 3 2 0 4]
 [2 0 3 4 1 3]
 [1 4 1 3 4 1]
 ...
 [1 2 0 4 2 1]
 [3 0 0 1 2 1]
 [2 3 4 1 3 3]]
```

So my X_train and Y_strain shapes are:

```
print(X.shape, Y.shape)
(350, 5, 1) (350, 6)
```

my model code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=5, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

is it right to process the data in this way?
Should I divide the matches into lists in the X_train? I mean, X_train should be a list of lists (list of matches) and within each match I have lists of 5 timesteps that go over the match? I have the same question for Y_train too, I've tried separating the labels into different lists like I did for X_train but I can't pass a list of labels in 3D.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Without exactly knowing the domain, I would say:

1: I would make the labels a single value instead of a list of ints,

2: Does a 'move' contain the layout of a whole board? If  so, then in theory a move is match independent since a board layout should be universal so to speak... but, if you try to predict a human players next move, then a match and thus a strategy might make sense to consider.

3: It's hard to see wether you loose context when producing your x_train.
Interesting project!

Comment: Thanks  @Anynamer and thanks for your interest in my project, I have added some information about my context as you advised. I tried to keep the numbers converted to baseN but as integers instead of lists of integers. So the shape of Y_train is now (350,) BUT my model doesn't learn, it can't calculate the loss and gives me loss: 0.0000e+00. Do you have any advice?